# CSS no longer applies on other server

Tags: php, css

Currently I am working on a music site and facing problem with css files.

On local server or company's testing server (*UNIX*) it's working fine, but when I uploaded the file on another server (Windows) to live, the CSS doesn't appear to be having an effect.

When I use Firebug, it says no CSS defined. If I use View Source and click on a CSS file link, it seems to work fine.

**Another issue:** If I echo any thing at header file then CSS works properly; same if I use inline CSS code. What may be the issue?

Here's my header file code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>xyz</title>
<base href="<?php echo HTTP_PATH; ?>/">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

**This is my old post and i got best answer of this post:**

Your server is serving the wrong content type for the CSS. When I look in the network tab, the .css file is served as text/html instead of text/css. This means that the browser doesn't interpret it as a stylesheet but as a html document, automatically wrapping the content in a  tag because it thinks it's missing. This is causing all your CSS to be ignored.

But confuse with that answer when I print any character at browser then how server serve .css file as text/css.

Can anyone explain it?

Comment: Why you tagged java ?

Comment: Is it Java, or PHP? Why is there a `<base>`?

Comment: That's a good question.  Since you said you posted it to a server, would you mind, please, giving me to URL so I can check for you?

Comment: I opened that URL and seems to be working just fine. Try clear your browser cache and try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server is serving the wrong content type for the CSS. When I look in the network tab, the .css file is served as `text/html` instead of `text/css`. This means that the browser doesn't interpret it as a stylesheet but as a html document, automatically wrapping the content in a `<html>` tag because it thinks it's missing. This is causing all your CSS to be ignored.

Comment: Because inline CSS is not in the stylesheet that has the wrong file encoding. It's inside the HTML document that is working.

Comment: @KajalSingh Normally the server is able to detect the correct content-type based on the file extension and send that information to the browser. The fix/solution will be different based on whether you are running IIS or Apache

Comment: You are saying .css file is served as text/html instead of text/css but when i echo anything then it served as text/css?
how it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Check the file encoding. 
Try transliterate the file to utf-8 - some symbols cannot be represented in windows servers, such as unix Carriage symbols (return/enter).
It might break your code...

Comment: but if any problem in transliterate then how inline css works?

Comment: It might be something related to you css file itself.
Can you provide a link to that page plz?